# Oracle data pump using java

Tags: java, database, oracle, datapump

I'am trying to use Oracle data pump using java. How can I export data from Oracle using java and retrieve a dump file of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can export using pl/sql: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_api.htm#sthref460

You can just invoke the pl/sql code from java. (see this http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1690300-using-data-pump-java.html  for example)